Distributional Partial derivative .
Question : For any constant real  $ K$ , we let $f(x,y)=K-x^2- y^2 $  for   $ x^2+y^2 <1$ and $f(x,y)=0$ elsewhere in $\mathbb R^2$
i. compute $D_xf$ and $D_yf$, (  here $D_xf$ means partial distributional derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, and there is an property is that $\langle D_xf,\phi\rangle=-\langle T,\frac {\partial \phi} {\partial x}\rangle$, where T is a distributional fucntion and $\phi$ is test function  . and also $T_\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}=D_xT_f$
Here I did't understand how to find this derivative .
I also try to find this , by using general partial derivative of a function . that is  $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}=2x $ is this answer is also valid for $D_xf$ . if yes then why ? if not , then what is the actual answer .
in another way  I try to find this answer by using $T_\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}=D_xT_f$.
$$T_\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}=D_xT_f $$
$$ \langle T_\frac {\partial f} {\partial x},\phi \rangle=\int \frac {\partial f} {\partial x}\phi dx=\int2x \phi dx = \langle 2x,\phi \rangle$$
hence answer is $\ 2x $ that is $D_xf=2x$
Please let me know that whether it is correct or not and also explain .
Thanks

The general idea for functions that are piecewise $C^1$ is that the derivative in the sense of distributions gives you the usual derivative on the domain of continuity + a Dirac measure on the set with jump discontinuities

@AhammadMostafaHossain And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Let $\phi\in C_C^\infty$ and let $f$ be the distribution defined as
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
K-x^2-y^2&, x^2+y^2<1\\\\
0&,\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, we have
$$\begin{align}
\langle \partial_xf,\phi\rangle&=-\langle f,\partial_x\phi\rangle\\\\
&=-\iint_{x^2+y^2<1}(K-x^2-y^2)\frac{\partial \phi(x,y)}{\partial x}\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=-\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}(K-x^2-y^2)\frac{\partial \phi(x,y)}{\partial x}\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=-\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left((K-x^2-y^2)\phi(x,y)\right)+2x\phi(x,y)\right)\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=-(K-1)\int_{-1}^1 \left(\phi(\sqrt{1-y^2},y)-\phi(-\sqrt{1-y^2},y)\right)\,dy\\\\&-\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} 2x\phi(x,y)\,dx\,dy\\\\
\end{align}$$
Hence, in distribution we see that
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}&=-(K-1)\left(\delta\left(x-\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)-\delta\left(x+\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)\right)-2x[1-H(x^2+y^2-1)]\\\\
&=-(K-1)2x\delta(x^2+y^2-1)-2x[1-H(x^2+y^2-1)]
\end{align}$$

@AhammadMostafaHossain Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Please let me know that how you got the last two line , I think there is typo in  the last 2nd line . Please explain last line .

@AhammadMostafaHossain Yes, there was a missing paranthesis in the second to last line, which has been edited.  To arrive at the last line, simply use the definiton of the composition $\delta(f(x))$, where here $f(x)=x^2+y^2-1$.  There are two location for which $f\equiv0$.  They are $x=\pm \sqrt{1-y^2}$.  Note that $|f'(x)|=|2x|$ at the zeros of $f$.  Can you proceed now?

yes . Thank you .

@AhammadMostafaHossain Pleased to hear.  And you're welcome.  My pleasure

@AhammadMostafaHossain And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ be a region with a smooth boundary and $\mathbf 1_\Omega$ the indicator function of $\Omega.$
Take $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^2)$ and let $\hat x$ denote the unit vector in the $x$ direction. Then, by the divergence theorem in two dimensions,
$$
\langle D_x\mathbf 1_\Omega, \phi \rangle
= -\langle \mathbf 1_\Omega, \partial_x\phi \rangle
= -\iint_\Omega \hat x\cdot \nabla\phi \, dA
= -\iint_\Omega \nabla\cdot(\hat x\phi) \, dA
\\
= -\oint_{\partial\Omega} \hat x\phi \cdot n\,dl
= -\oint_{\partial\Omega} \phi \, n_x\,dl
,
$$
where $n=(n_x,n_y)$ is the outwards pointing unit vector on the boundary.
Likewise,
$$
\langle D_y\mathbf 1_\Omega, \phi \rangle
= -\oint_{\partial\Omega} \phi \, n_y\,dl
$$
and the distributional gradient of $\mathbf 1_\Omega$ is given by
$$
\langle \nabla \mathbf 1_\Omega, \phi \rangle
= -\oint_{\partial\Omega} \phi \, n\,dl
,
$$
which means that it is the boundary length measure times the inwards pointing normal. Let us write this as $\nabla \mathbf 1_\Omega = -n\,dl.$
Next, if $h\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ and $u\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^2)$ is any distribution, then
$$
\langle D_x(hu), \phi \rangle
= -\langle hu, \partial_x\phi \rangle
= -\langle u, h \partial_x\phi \rangle
= -\langle u, \partial_x (h\phi) - (\partial_x h) \phi \rangle
\\
= -\langle u, \partial_x (h\phi) \rangle + \langle u, (\partial_x h) \phi \rangle
= \langle D_x u, h\phi \rangle + \langle (\partial_x h) u, \phi \rangle
\\
= \langle h D_x u, \phi \rangle + \langle (\partial_x h) u, \phi \rangle
= \langle h D_x u + (\partial_x h) u, \phi \rangle,
$$
i.e. $D_x (hu) = h D_x u + (\partial_x h) u.$
Likewise we have $D_y (hu) = h D_y u + (\partial_y h) u,$ and as vectors,
$$
\nabla(hu) = h \nabla u + (\nabla h) u.$
$$
Now, your $f$ can be written as $h\mathbf 1_\Omega,$ where $h(x,y) = K-x^2-y^2$ and $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2 < 1 \}.$ Thus,
$$
\nabla f
= \nabla (h\mathbf 1_\Omega)
= h (\nabla\mathbf 1_\Omega) + (\nabla h) \mathbf 1_\Omega
\\
= (K-x^2-y^2) (-n\,dl) + (-2x\,\hat x-2y\,\hat y) \mathbf 1_\Omega
\\
= (K-1) (-n\,dl) + (-2x\,\hat x-2y\,\hat y) \mathbf 1_\Omega
.
$$
