distribution find $Df_x$ and $Df_y$ derivatives in the distribution sense and when this functions locally integrable?
given function $f(x,y) = K-x^2 - y^2$ when $x^2 + y^2<1$ otherwise zero.
question is find $Df_x$ and $Df_y$ in distrubtion sense and which of K this functions are integrable?
I know it is two get integration by parts and after that I stuck could please help me. I would be really appreciate. Thanks

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4975378/168433 ?
